# How to write a query when 3 fields combined are unique

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this in my db

[image]

xtra_scope_id + platform_id + player_uuid combined together are unique.

Given an xtra_scope_id (let’s assume 2) I would like to write a query that returns 2 columns:

1. player_uuid
2. the count of rows related to that player_uuid grouping those rows by xtra_scope_id (and ignoring the multiple rows that platform_id could generate) (How many xtra_scope_id does that player have?)

For example
[image]

Player_uuid 0069ce60-93b2-44a0-baf1-6fe7200e4946  should have only 1 as count, because he has rows only with xtra_scope_id = 2

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Unrelated comment most likey to the answer but it looks a bit wierd data, why can the `platform_id` and `created_at` be `NULL` ("unknown" for SQL)

Comment: @RaymondNijland that's not relevant for the question indeed :) By the way we want to clean up those data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the title of your question, you can use `count(distinct)`:

```
select player_id,
       count(distinct xtra_scope_id, platform_id, player_uuid) as uniq_combos
from t
group by player_id;
```

Comment: I want to ignore platform_id, basically I want to count how many xtra_scope_id does any player have.
I think I can modify your query removing platform_id.
Thanks

Comment: @Giggioz . . . The question explicitly states:  "xtra_scope_id + platform_id + player_uuid combined together are unique."  But you can modify the answer to suit your needs.

Comment: read bullet point number 2. Anyway, thanks for sharing your solution, from that I was able to solve the query I needed.